# How to detect peaks in audio file?

Tags: audio

Given a several minute Wave file with short clicking sounds at semi regular intervals, how would I go about getting millisecond timestamps for each of the clicks? I'm trying to [verify the accuracy of a single second timer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61528/how-to-do-1-or-more-photos-per-second-without-jitter-using-a-canon-7d). Preferably using only the shell, Python, Ruby or other standard *nix tools.

Comment: can you post an example .wav recorded file showing the peaks (a few seconds of .wav showing the peaks will be enough)? It might help to find a solution

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it sounds like a programming question to me. Perhaps this one is for Stack Overflow?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I abandoned it :( However, I've marked your answer as accepted since it should do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly `sox` would be an option.

Invoked like this:

```
sox sound.wav sound.dat
```

it writes a `textual representation of the sample data` to the file `sound.dat`. Depending on the options you can get a file with the *time since the beginning* in the *first column* and a *normalized sample volume* in *second column*, e.g.:

```
; Sample Rate 44100
; Channels 1
               0     -0.026428223 
   2.2675737e-05     -0.022186279 
   4.5351474e-05     -0.022186279 
   6.8027211e-05     -0.022827148 
   9.0702948e-05     -0.022491455 
   0.00011337868     -0.025756836 
   0.00013605442     -0.021850586 
   0.00015873016     -0.026428223 
    0.0001814059      -0.02545166 
   0.00020408163     -0.023162842 
   0.00022675737      -0.02545166 
   0.00024943311     -0.018249512 
   0.00027210884     -0.018249512 
   0.00029478458     -0.019226074 
   0.00031746032      -0.01663208 
   0.00034013605     -0.013702393 
   0.00036281179     -0.014984131 
   0.00038548753     -0.015319824
```

A bit of `awk` could reveal the peeks with a timestamp:

```
$ awk '$2 > 0.6 { print }' < sound.dat
; Sample Rate 44100
; Channels 1
       1.1002721       0.64196777 
       1.1004762       0.65371704
```

`man sox` and `man soxformat` should give more info.

Comment: Output data columns (1 per input channel) are [-1.0,1.0] so you should take the absolute value (of all channels) for accurate results. It's useful also to use `printf("%.12f",..)` in awk, sox uses `%g` for its output, the presence of *E notation* would complicate further processing, e.g. via `sort -n`.